Strange bug when starting Ubuntu LiveCD under VirtualBox
When I start a Ubuntu ISO in VirtualBox (I tried with 24.04 and 24.10), the tracker-extract package segfaults after the desktop and the installer appear. The VM has 65536 MB of RAM. The _usr_libexec_tracker-extract-3.1000.crash file is in this pastebin.

65536 MB - you really have that amount of actual RAM? Update Virtualbox?
